# Create my first own project

Tags: chisel

Following this [tutorial](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/latest/getting-started.html) at chapter 6 I tried to create my first own project.
I create my directory "first" with two files: build.sbt and first.scala ( exactly as described by the tutorial, I just used another name, "first" for my project instead of "hello" ).
But, when I type the following comand:

```
sbt run --backend c
```

I have this error:

```
[error] Not a valid command: backend (similar: append)
[error] backend
[error]        ^
```

What's wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Francesco

Comment: I understood the problem. The command isn't correct beacuse some quotes are missing. The correct commend is: sbt "run --beckend c"

Answer (score 1):

the arguments with `run` need to be surrounded with quotes:

`sbt "run --backend c"`

(tutorials have been updated to reflect the proper use)

Comment: Please reword your answer to look like answer instead of "thank you note".